# Remove slash on redirect without .htaccess

Tags: apache, apache2

I would like to do a redirect from http to https and it's ok with this without .htaccess:

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{HTTPS} off [OR]
RewriteCond %{HTTP:X-Forwarded-Proto} !https
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ https://%{SERVER_NAME}/%{REQUEST_URI} [R=301,L]
```

But the problem appears when I access to my domain and put a context. 
The redirect added an slash at the end:

ko --> http://guif.duckdns.org/ip -> https://guif.duckdns.org/ip/

ok --> http://guif.duckdns.org -> https://guif.duckdns.org

This is my http.conf

```
[root@srv02 conf]# cat httpd.conf | egrep -v '#|^$'
ServerRoot "/etc/httpd"
Listen 80
Include conf.modules.d/*.conf
User apache
Group apache
ServerAdmin root@localhost
ServerName guif.duckdns.org:80
ServerTokens Prod
ServerSignature Off 
TraceEnable off

RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{HTTPS} off [OR] 
RewriteCond %{HTTP:X-Forwarded-Proto} !https
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ https://%{SERVER_NAME}/%{REQUEST_URI} [R=301,L]

<Directory />
    AllowOverride none
    Require all denied
</Directory>
DocumentRoot "/var/www/html"
<Directory "/var/www">
    AllowOverride None
    Require all granted
</Directory>
<Directory "/var/www/html">
    Options -ExecCGI -FollowSymLinks -Indexes
    AllowOverride None
    Require all granted
</Directory>
<IfModule dir_module>
    DirectoryIndex index.html
</IfModule>
<Files ".ht*">
    Require all denied
</Files>
ErrorLog "logs/error_log"
LogLevel warn
<IfModule log_config_module>
    LogFormat "%h %l %u %t \"%r\" %>s %b %D \"%{Referer}i\" \"%{User-Agent}i\"" combined
    LogFormat "%h %l %u %t \"%r\" %>s %b %D" common
    <IfModule logio_module>
      LogFormat "%h %l %u %t \"%r\" %>s %b %D \"%{Referer}i\" \"%{User-Agent}i\" %I %O" combined
    </IfModule>
    CustomLog "logs/access_log" combined
</IfModule>
<IfModule alias_module>
    ScriptAlias /cgi-bin/ "/var/www/cgi-bin/"
</IfModule>
<Directory "/var/www/cgi-bin">
    AllowOverride None
    Options None
    Require all granted
</Directory>
<IfModule mime_module>
    TypesConfig /etc/mime.types
    AddType application/x-compress .Z
    AddType application/x-gzip .gz .tgz
    AddType text/html .shtml
    AddOutputFilter INCLUDES .shtml
</IfModule>
AddDefaultCharset UTF-8
<IfModule mime_magic_module>
    MIMEMagicFile conf/magic
</IfModule>
EnableSendfile on
IncludeOptional conf.d/*.conf
```

And this is the ssl.con

```
Listen 443 https
SSLPassPhraseDialog exec:/usr/libexec/httpd-ssl-pass-dialog
SSLSessionCache         shmcb:/run/httpd/sslcache(512000)
SSLSessionCacheTimeout  300
SSLRandomSeed startup file:/dev/urandom  256
SSLRandomSeed connect builtin
SSLCryptoDevice builtin
<VirtualHost _default_:443>
ErrorLog logs/ssl_error_log
TransferLog logs/ssl_access_log
LogLevel warn
SSLEngine on
SSLProtocol all -SSLv3 -TLSv1 -TLSv1.1
SSLCipherSuite ECDHE-ECDSA-AES128-GCM-SHA256:ECDHE-RSA-AES128-GCM-SHA256:ECDHE-ECDSA-AES256-GCM-SHA384:ECDHE-RSA-AES256-GCM-SHA384:ECDHE-ECDSA-CHACHA20-POLY1305:ECDHE-RSA-CHACHA20-POLY1305:DHE-RSA-AES128-GCM-SHA256:DHE-RSA-AES256-GCM-SHA384
SSLCertificateFile /etc/letsencrypt/live/guif.duckdns.org/fullchain.pem
SSLCertificateKeyFile /etc/letsencrypt/live/guif.duckdns.org/privkey.pem
SSLCertificateChainFile /etc/letsencrypt/live/guif.duckdns.org/fullchain.pem
<Files ~ "\.(cgi|shtml|phtml|php3?)$">
    SSLOptions +StdEnvVars
</Files>
<Directory "/var/www/cgi-bin">
    SSLOptions +StdEnvVars
</Directory>
BrowserMatch "MSIE [2-5]" \
         nokeepalive ssl-unclean-shutdown \
         downgrade-1.0 force-response-1.0
CustomLog logs/ssl_request_log \
          "%t %h %{SSL_PROTOCOL}x %{SSL_CIPHER}x \"%r\" %b %D"
</VirtualHost>
```

why?

Comment: I'm not using .htaccess

Comment: It doesn't matter, the rewrite syntax is the same